# How to select the contents in the text view textrea in wp_editor?

Tags: php, plugin-development, jquery, metabox, javascript

I am trying to count words among other text stats entered into the default post editor (wp_editor).

Its supposed the write word count out to *<div id="word count">* in the meta box immediately below wp_editor.

I have been able to properly select the **visual editor** *copy* but not the **text editor** *copy*.

I have included all code below. The javascript in question is enclosed in "Begin" and "End" comments.

Thanks for your help,
Tim

**Plugin Directory Structure:**

```
plugin-shell > plugin-shell.php
plugin-shell > assets > js > admin > wordcount.js
plugin-shell > assets > css > admin > style.css
plugin-shell > assets > css > frontend > style.css
```

**Admin Stylesheet:**

```
#after_editor-sortables {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#wordcount {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border-color: #525252;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var i=0;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    setInterval(function(){
        var replacedTags = "";
        var replacedEntities = "";
        var tinymcevalue = "";

        console.log('Text: ' + tinymcevalue);
        console.log('Display: ' + $('textarea#content').css('display'));

        // BEGIN

        if($('textarea#content').css('display') == 'none'){ 
            tinymcevalue =    $('#content_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').html(); 
        } else { 
            tinymcevalue = $('textarea#content').contents(); // Failed
         // tinymcevalue = $('textarea#content').html();     // Failed
        }

        // END

        var regexTags = /<[^>]+>/g;
        var regexEntities = /&lt;[\s\S]+?&gt;/gi;
        if (tinymcevalue !== "") {    
            replacedTags = tinymcevalue.replace(regexTags , "");
            replacedEntities = replacedTags.replace(regexEntities , "");
        }

        var wordscount = replacedEntities.split(" ");

        $("#wordcount").text(wordscount.length);
    }, 5000)
});
```

**Plugin Shell:**

```
<?php

/*
   Plugin Name: PluginShell
   Plugin URI: http://www.pluginshell.com/
   Description: Aenean Vestibulum Risus Commodo Ullamcorper
   Author: PluginShell
   Author URI: http://www.pluginshell.com/
   Version: 0.0.0
*/

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
class Plugin_Shell {
   /**
    *
    * CONSTRUCTOR
    * Adds all actions and filters to the class
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/ 
    function __construct() {
        //Actions
        add_action( 'init',                  array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_register_post_type'       ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init',            array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_register_and_build_fields') );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',    array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_enqueue_style'            ) );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_enqueue_wordcount_js'     ) );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_enqueue_options_style'    ) );
        add_action( 'admin_menu',            array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_add_meta_boxes'           ) );
        add_action( 'admin_menu',            array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_options_page'             ) );
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes',        array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_add_contextable_meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post',             array( &$this, 'plugin_shell_meta_box_save' ), 1, 2      );
        add_action( 'edit_form_after_editor',array( &$this, 'add_after_editor_meta_boxes'           ) );
        add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', array( &$this, 'add_after_title_meta_boxes'            ) );

    }

   /**
    *
    * PHP4 CONSTRUCTOR
    * Calls __construct to create class
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/ 
    function plugin_shell() {
        $this->__construct();
    }

   /**
    *
    * LOAD JS ONTO THE ADMIN PAGE
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/ 
    function plugin_shell_enqueue_wordcount_js() {
        //die('BEGIN: plugin_shell_enqueue_wordcount_js');
        wp_register_script( 'plugin-shell-wordcount-js',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/admin/wordcount.js' );
        //die('MIDDLE: plugin_shell_enqueue_wordcount_js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-shell-wordcount-js' ); 
        //die('END: plugin_shell_enqueue_wordcount_js');
    }

   /**
    *
    * LOAD CSS INTO THE WEBSITE'S FRONT END
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/ 
    function plugin_shell_enqueue_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'plugin-shell-style',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/css/frontend/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-shell-style' ); 
    }

   /**
    *
    * LOAD CSS INTO THE ADMIN PAGE
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/ 
    function plugin_shell_enqueue_options_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'plugin-shell-options-style',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/css/admin/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-shell-options-style' ); 
    }

   /**
    * Register meta box context location: after_editor
    *
    * @return null
    **/
    function add_after_editor_meta_boxes() {
        global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
        # Output the `after_editor` meta boxes:
        do_meta_boxes( get_current_screen(), 'after_editor', $post );
    }

   /**
    * Register meta box context location: after_title
    *
    * @return null
    **/
    function add_after_title_meta_boxes() {
        global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
        # Output the `after_title` meta boxes:
        do_meta_boxes( get_current_screen(), 'after_title', $post );
    }

   /**
    *
    * REGISTER CUSTOM POST TYPE: plugin_shell
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function plugin_shell_register_post_type() {
        $options = get_option('plugin_shell_options');

        register_post_type( 'plugin_shell',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Plugin Shell' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'term' ),
                    'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Term' ),
                    'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Term' ),
                    'new_item' => __( 'New Term' ),
                    'view' => __( 'View Term' ),
                    'view_item' => __( 'View Term' ),
                    'search_items' => __( 'Search Term' ),
                    'not_found' => __( 'No Terms found' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Terms found in Trash' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book-alt',
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $options['plugin_shell_slug_url_setting'] ? get_post($options['plugin_shell_slug_url_setting'])->post_name : 'plugin-shell', 'with_front' => false )
            )
        );
    }

/*********************************************************
    BEGIN: CONTEXTABLE META BOX
 *********************************************************/

   /**
    *
    * CALLS ALL OF THE FUNCTIONS RESPONSIBLE FOR RENDERING THE CONTEXTABLE PLUGIN SHELL META BOX
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function plugin_shell_add_contextable_meta_box() {
        $this->_plugin_shell_add_contextable();
    }

   /**
    *
    * RENDERS THE META BOX 
    * Responsible for allowing the user to enter the plugin shell term.
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function _plugin_shell_add_contextable() {
        add_meta_box( 
            'contextable-meta-box', 
            __( 'Extended Context Meta Box', 'pluginshell-textdomain' ), 
            array( &$this, '_display_contextable_meta_box' ), 
            'plugin_shell', // CHANGE TO DESIRED post-type
            'after_editor', // CHANGE THIS TO 'after_editor' || 'after_title' || OR OTHER VALID CONTEXT LOCATION
            'default' 
        );
    }

   /**
    * 
    * DISPLAYS THE CONTENTS OF THE PLUGIN SHELL TERM META BOX
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/ 
    function _display_contextable_meta_box() {

        printf( '<div id="wordcount"></div><br />&nbsp;<br />' );
    }

/*********************************************************
    END: CONTEXTABLE META BOX
 *********************************************************/

   /**
    * 
    * CALLS ALL OF THE FUNCTIONS RESPONSIBLE FOR RENDERING THE PLUGIN SHELL META BOX
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function plugin_shell_add_meta_boxes() {
        $this->_plugin_shell_add_meta_box();
    }

   /**
    *
    * RENDERS THE META BOX 
    * Responsible for allowing the user to enter the plugin shell term.
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function _plugin_shell_add_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box( 'plugin_shell', __('Plugin Shell Extra Meta Box', 'pluginshell-textdomain'), array( &$this, '_plugin_shell_definiton_meta_box' ), 'plugin_shell', 'normal', 'high' );
    }

   /**
    * 
    * DISPLAYS THE CONTENTS OF THE PLUGIN SHELL TERM META BOX
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/ 
    function _plugin_shell_definiton_meta_box() {
        ?>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>

<p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>

<p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
<?php
    }

   /**
    * 
    * SAVES PLUGIN SHELL TERM
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function plugin_shell_meta_box_save( $post_id, $post ) {
        $key = '_plugin_shell_term';

        //  verify the nonce
        if ( !isset($_POST['_plugin_shell_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_plugin_shell_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
            return;

        //  don't try to save the data under autosave, ajax, or future post.
        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
        if ( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) return;
        if ( defined('DOING_CRON') && DOING_CRON ) return;

        //  is the user allowed to edit the URL?
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) || $post->post_type != 'plugin_shell' )
            return;

        $value = isset( $_POST[$key] ) ? $_POST[$key] : '';

        if ( $value ) {
            //  save/update
            $my_post = array();
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else {
            //  delete if blank
            delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
        }

    }

   /**
    *
    * ADMIN MENU AND
    * SETTING FEILDS
    *
    **/

   /**
    * 
    * BUILD THE SETTINGS OPTIONS PAGE
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function _plugin_shell_build_options_page() { 
        ?>
        <div id="plugin-shell-options-wrap">
            <div class="icon32" id="icon-tools"> <br /> </div>
            <form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php settings_fields('plugin_shell_option_group'); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>
                <p class="submit">
                    <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
                </p>
            </form>
            <p><hr></p>
            <p>* After editing the Slug the Permalinks Settings must be saved again.</p>
        </div>
        <?php 
    }

   /**
    * 
    * REGISTER SETTINGS AND FIELDS FOR OPTIONS PAGE
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function plugin_shell_register_and_build_fields() {
        register_setting('plugin_shell_option_group', 'plugin_shell_option_mainpage', 'plugin_shell_validate_setting');
        add_settings_section('plugin_shell_settings_general', 'Plugin Shell General Settings', array( &$this, '_plugin_shell_settings_fields'), __FILE__);
    }

   /**
    * 
    * RENDER THE SLUG SELECTION SETTINGS FIELD
    *
    * @since 0.9.2
    *
    **/
    function _plugin_shell_settings_fields() {
        add_settings_field('slug', 'Mainpage:', array( &$this, '_plugin_shell_slug_url_setting'), __FILE__, 'plugin_shell_settings_general');
    } 

   /**
    * 
    * SANITIZE OPTIONS
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function plugin_shell_validate_setting($plugin_shell_options) {
        return $plugin_shell_options;
    }


   /**
    * 
    * GET DROPDOWN OF ALL PAGES FOR SLUG SETTING OPTION
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function _plugin_shell_slug_url_setting() {
        $options = get_option('plugin_shell_options');
        wp_dropdown_pages(array('name' => 'theme_options[plugin_shell_slug_url_setting]', 'selected' => $options['plugin_shell_slug_url_setting'] ));
    }

   /**
    * 
    * ADD THE OPTIONS PAGE
    *
    * @since 0.0.0
    *
    **/
    function plugin_shell_options_page() { 
        add_options_page('Plugin Shell', 'Plugin Shell', 'administrator', __FILE__, array( &$this, '_plugin_shell_build_options_page' ) );
    }
};

/**
 * 
 * INSTANTIATE CLASS plugin_shell
 *
 * @since 0.0.0
 *
 **/
$PluginShell = new plugin_shell;

?>
```

Comment: WordPress have `word-count.js` that used under `post.js`. It's better if you use it.

Comment: "The reason is that the default count counts all words including html tags." are you sure?

Comment: @Jevuska I am going to be running some specialized text stats not just this one and need to solve this one so I can extrapolate the others. I appreciate you taking some of your time to help. This it really just solving a javascript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TinyMCE editor have functions in his API to get the content of the editor.
To get all content of selection use the follow source:

`tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();`

WordPress have since 4.3 a lot fo changes on the editor. Use always the API 4 for find the right functions in the documentation page.
[Here for documentation](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.dom.Selection) about get content inside the editor. All helpful functions of the API find you in this link below.

To get all content use `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode()`.

For the usage in the WordPress environment can you also use jQuery, is a part of the core. As example create a instance of tinymce and add your source.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'Your_Namespace', function( editor ) {

                if ( typeof(
                        tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent()
                    ) != 'undefined' ) {
                    marked = true;
                }

                if ( marked == true ) {
                    var content       = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent(),
                        start_content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getStart().nodeName,
                        all           = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode()
                }

                // Debug in Console
                console.log(all);

    } );
} );
```